# OAuth 2.0 vs JWT

Tags: php, django, authentication, oauth, jwt

I have a web application which has several serving api's. Now for the current time being I have authenticated the user using JWT token, which stores the user's id and then i can access resources related to that user with the help of the token.

Recently I also want to integrate login via social media. So i want to ask can i just use OAuth 2.0 for just social media login. Is there a way to mix both of these ways. Or I have to replace my JWT authentication with OAuth.
What i have heard is that OAuth is bit of complex and time taking.

My web portal back-end is on both PHP and Django. API's are served via Django platform.

Answer (score 1):

> So i want to ask can i just use OAuth 2.0 for just social media login

Yes.

The OAuth 2.0 authorization grant flow will allow you to confirm if that user is really who they say they are on that social media site (e.g. I am theuser@gmail.com, and I can prove it by enabling you to successfully call the profile API and retrieve my email).

Once you have authenticated the user using OAuth 2.0, you can provision JWT tokens the same way as you are currently doing.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 is a specification for authorization, but NOT for authentication. Use OpenID Connect on top of OAuth 2.0 for that.